# What's the soap api call body for changing the category id of an existing data extension in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions

I'm working in Postman with various SOAP API calls.

I'm new to using 'UpdateRequest'. I've been able to update data in rows of a data extension, but not the properties of a data extension, such as category id.

My goals are to move existing data extensions to new folders by changing the category ids via a soap call and to learn more about UpdateRequest.

**Example of a call I tried** (not working - the category id does not update):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
    xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:1234-1234-1234-1234-1432</a:MessageID>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">{{soapEndPoint}}/Service.asmx</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Objects xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"></PartnerKey>
                <ModifiedDate xsi:nil="true"></ModifiedDate>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"></ObjectID>
                <CustomerKey>12345-12345678</CustomerKey>
                <Properties>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>CategoryID</Name>
                        <Value>123456</Value>
                    </Property>
                </Properties>
            </Objects>
        </UpdateRequest>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**The response** (says 'Data Extension updated.', but the category id is not updated)

```
<soap:Body>
    <UpdateResponse xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Results>
            <StatusCode>OK</StatusCode>
            <StatusMessage>Data Extension updated.</StatusMessage>
            <OrdinalID>0</OrdinalID>
            <Object xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ModifiedDate xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID>799d2d6b-495e-eb11-a2f8-123123123</ObjectID>
                <CustomerKey>123456-5432-4e87-123-d2f4713e449b</CustomerKey>
            </Object>
        </Results>
        <RequestID>213456-99dd-3456-3456-3456346346</RequestID>
        <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
    </UpdateResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CategoryID doesn't need to be nested inside properties tags. Below is an example that works in my environment. I usually just pass the External Key and CategoryID (Folder ID) but you can add additional fields you need. Note: you'll likely need to change the {{et_subdomain}} and {{dne_etAccessToken}} variables used in my Postman collection.

There are a variety of sample calls in a collection my team manages here: https://api.mcexperts.ninja/. This specific call isn't in there but a similar update example is. The collection has almost all the REST routes but SOAP still needs to be more thoroughly built out. Hope this helps!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Update</a:Action>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://{{et_subdomain}}.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
    <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{dne_etAccessToken}}</fueloauth>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Options /> 
        <Objects xsi:type="ns1:DataExtension" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <CustomerKey>5259588A-29E0-446E-ACD4-17D7F8490933</CustomerKey> 
            <CategoryID>1691183</CategoryID>
        </Objects>
    </UpdateRequest>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Works perfectly!